# Dynamically change hover enabled option

Tags: javascript, highcharts, hover

I want that when I hover on top of the chart nothing happens (i.e. hover enabled:false) but when I click on the button bellow the chart the hover enabled turns to true.

Right now I'm using these two functions for turning on the hover when I click on the buttons below the chart:

```
function update() {
  chart.series[0].data[0].setState('hover');
};

function unset() {

    chart.series[0].data[0].setState('');

}
```

These functions works great for clicking the buttons but when I hover on top of the chart the halo still appears. How can I do this?

The JSFiffle is this: http://jsfiddle.net/u6ftv3wm/

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand... So you want nothing to happen when you hover but when you click on the buttons? What do you mean with enabled:false? What do you want to set?

Comment: Yes, I want that nothing happens when I hover, but when I click on the button below, the behavior for the hover is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the series with new options like that:

```
// Activate the button for update
function update() {
  chart.series[0].update({
    states: {
      hover: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  });
}
// Activate the button for unset
function unsetColor() {
  chart.series[0].update({
    states: {
      hover: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9hmws30k/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your current code

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        states: {
            hover: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    }
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzndh74g/)

Comment: If I had that part to the code, then the buttons don't work. That's my problem